# JSON data not shown on second time an activity is opened

Tags: android

I have an activity that retreives objects from JSON.
The first time the activity is shown, all works fine.

But if the user goes forward and back and opens it again, then any data is shown.

This is my code:

package com.solinpromex.casajuventudtrescantos;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class DondeEsta_T1_MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables

     private static final String TAG_NAME = "nombreCategoria";
        private static final String TAG_ID = "idPrueba";
        private String name = "Categoria";
        private String id = "id";
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    DondeEsta_T1_ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String ID_DES= "id_des";
    static String TITULO_DES = "titulo_des";
    static String CATEGORIAS_DES = "categoria_des";
    static String LUGAR_DES = "lugar_des";
    static String LATITUD_DES = "latitud_des";
    static String LONGITUD_DES = "longitud_des";
    static String IMAGEN_DES = "imagen_des";
    static String DESCRIPCION_DES = "descripcion_des";
    static String WEB_DES = "web_des";
    static String MAIL_DES = "mail_des";
    static String TEL_DES = "tel_des";
    static String LUGAR_CORTO = "lugar_corto";
    static String idPrueba = "idPrueba";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("MVASCO", "context is null!");
         // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

     // Get JSON values from previous intent
       name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
       id = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
       idPrueba =in.getStringExtra(idPrueba);

        setContentView(R.layout.dondeesta_t1_listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        //new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array


        //  Log.v("categoria para pasar a la URL", id_categoria_donde_esta);
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address

            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://.hidden url.../app_php_files/recuperar_categorias_donde_esta_t1.php?cat="+idPrueba);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Categorias");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("id_des", jsonobject.getString("id_des"));
                    map.put("titulo_des", jsonobject.getString("titulo_des"));

                    map.put("categoria_des", jsonobject.getString("categoria_des"));
                    map.put("lugar_des", jsonobject.getString("lugar_des"));
                    map.put("latitud_des", jsonobject.getString("latitud_des"));
                    map.put("longitud_des", jsonobject.getString("longitud_des"));
                    map.put("descripcion_des", jsonobject.getString("descripcion_des"));
                    map.put("web_des", jsonobject.getString("web_des"));
                    map.put("mail_des", jsonobject.getString("mail_des"));
                    map.put("imagen_des", "http://www.solinpromex.com/casajuventud/sitios/"+jsonobject.getString("imagen_des"));                    
                    map.put("tel_des", jsonobject.getString("tel_des"));
                    map.put("lugar_corto", jsonobject.getString("lugar_corto"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new DondeEsta_T1_ListViewAdapter(DondeEsta_T1_MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this

```
   Intent in = getIntent();

 // Get JSON values from previous intent
   name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
   id = in.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
   idPrueba =in.getStringExtra(idPrueba);
```

into the Method onResume then it should work i think

Take also a look in this overview of the Lifecycle of an Activity
http://www.android-app-market.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Android-Activity-Lifecycle.png

Comment: Thank you, but if I put this into onresum method, then the list is not shown the first time I open the activity...?

Comment: So if it worked in the first try cut your code into a method and call it in onCreate and also in onResume